# How to run cronjob specific time (UTC) with Node-Cron?

Tags: node.js, npm, cron-task, node-cron

I use node-cron library for working with schedule task. I want to run my task every 1hr ( 00.00, 01.00, 02.00...24.00) in timezone of UTC but it doesn't work ( time was incorrect)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron#schedule):

> See [IANA time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) for valid values, such as `Asia/Shanghai`, `Asia/Kolkata`, `America/Sao_Paulo`.

You can see list of tz database time zones at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

```js
let task24 = cron.schedule('0 * * * *' async () => {
    // task
}, { timezone: 'Etc/UTC' })
```

### Update

There's a [**memory leak bug**](https://github.com/node-cron/node-cron/issues/358#issuecomment-1191320003) if you set the `node-cron`'s `options.timezone`. Unless the issue is fixed, use [croner](https://github.com/hexagon/croner) instead. Here's [how to migrate from `node-cron` to `croner`](https://github.com/Hexagon/croner/blob/master/docs/MIGRATION.md#migrating-from-node-cron).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the time you want. You can use [this website](https://crontab.guru/every-1-hour) to do this.

Or use this example :

```js
var cron = require('node-cron');

cron.schedule("0 * * * *", () => { // 0 * * * * = every houre at minute 0
    console.log("running a task every houre");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

// If you want to run it at a specific time it can be like this:

// It will run every day at 10:36:00 AM

```
const cron = require('node-cron');
cron.schedule('00 36 10 * * *', () => {
    console.log(new Date());
});
```